# How to update/refresh google cloud shell output for virtual machine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am using google cloud virtual machines to train a ML, which takes hours.

Sometimes the output stops refreshing, the step and loss stay the same, even though I know the model is still training since it keeps saving checkpoints to my storage.

Is there a way to refresh this output?

Comment: What are you using? IA Platform? ML tech running on GCE instances? Also, are you seeing the output from Cloud Shell? It'll help to clarify what resources are involved.

Comment: I am setting up TPU VM instances and running tpu training, according to the tpu quickstart guide https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/quickstart . Yes, I see the output in the shell for a while, but eventually the shell stops updating the training output

Comment: Since it's mentioned in the title of the question it might be related to Cloud Shell. If you're using it to run `ctpu` you should know that these Cloud Shell "machines" are evicted after  a certain time and, new activity for instance, provisions a new one. Is this your case? Have you tried using a different shell to run your jobs?